# Downloading LASTools on Windows 10, QGIS 2.18.24 - Error Message

Tags: qgis, lastools

Following the instructions on this page;
[How to install LAStools toolbox in QGIS](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/)

I came across this error when I tried to define the path to my LASTools folder in the QGIS Processing Toolbox Menu [C:\Lastools]

[image: LASTools Error in QGIS]

Please could anyone explain to me how I can fix this error?

Comment: Error seems to say that you do not  have MSYS http://mingw.org/wiki/msys installed.

Comment: Many thanks I didn't realize it wasn't included in the QGIS standalone package